# Azure Mobile Service Local Username & Pass

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to use the "try it now" feature when running azure mobile services locally but it is asking for a username and password. Can anyone tell me what these credentials are ?

As far as I know running it locally should not require a user/pass. When I deploy it to azure I am able to correctly try it out using the application key as password and no user. This however does not work when running locally.

Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSrEx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read theses articles

[Microsoft’s Windows App Studio Beta: Connecting a Menu App to Azure Mobile Service](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/microsoft-windows-app-studio-beta-connecting-a-menu-app-to-azure-mobile-service/)

[Microsoft Azure Mobile Service: How to create the Azure Mobile Service in Azure Portal](http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/how-to-create-the-azure-mobile-service-in-azure-portal/)

Which provide all tips to create/use Azure Mobile Services.

in the first link I provided, I explain to "Running the Services" and in

"Running the Services > Server" you have all details you need:

> If we click on “try it out”, it requires a key to access the documentation, that key is provided in the [Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), by selecting the MyMenuApp Azure Mobile Service and then at the bottom has the option for it

[image]

> By clicking in the Manage Keys we will get

[image]

Comment: I originally did follow the two links you provided but for some strange reason it was asking for a login still. I resorted to re-downloading the project and adding it to my existing project again. All working now thanks.

Comment: Silly mistake I made but posting back here incase anyone runs into the same problem. In my WebApiConfig I had `config.SetIsHosted(true);` This should be set to  `config.SetIsHosted(false);` when running localhost.

Comment: how do I get the application key after hosting in IIS manager?